# Is this "Retired Sectors Count" correct for brand new disk Seagate CONSTELLATION ES 7200.3?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I have bought a brand new Seagate CONSTELLATION ES 7200.3 drive. It was laying in my desk's drawer for over a year, but now I decided to connect it to my PC.

When I first switched on the computer with the drive connected I was hearing a strange noise during the drive rotation. Something very strange I did not heard before from any drive. Something like quiet high-pitched sound of an angle grinder. I worked as sys-admin for over 15 years but it was something new for me.

Second boot and the sound disappeared, but made me a little suspicious about the condition of the drive. I did some quick S.M.A.R.T tests, but everything is OK.

Please advice if this is correct "Retired Sectors Count":

[image: all drive S.M.A.R.T attributes]

Comment: It's a pity that you have chosen to believe that your disk is failing. From the formula that this guy copied from my answer with no understanding, it's completely linear: as 94 is 4%, the total number of spare sectors is (94/4)*100= 2350. The pre-fail threshold of 10 is then 2350*0.9=2115. If you think that 94 is too near to 2115, then fine with me, it's your money.

Comment: @harrymc The disk did not finished long term smart test and  the number of  retired sectors increased to 104 . So the problem is progressing.

Comment: @harrymc did you removed your answer ? If it was not you, somebody else cleaned the comments and answers. It was not me. Probably @ giacomo1968 as I can see he edited my question.

Comment: Yes, I removed it. As you chose to believe some strange allegations about disk health and spare sectors, there was no point in leaving it in place. 94 out of 2350 is nothing, the disk was made for it with this lot of spare sectors. What's important is that it remains stable, which yours isn't, so the conclusion is that the disk is dying.

Comment: @harrymc, Why not leave it in place? There's plenty of Q's with multiple answers that do not necessarily agree with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's not normal to have 94 reallocated sectors on a brand new drive**. This alone should be enough reason to RMA the drive. Weird sounds are always reason (enough) for concern as well. Everything added up makes this a no-brainer IMO.

Unlike what is claimed, these are not sectors that were detected during testing in factory because such sectors aren't added to the grown defects list or G-List but to the P-List instead. P-List becomes part of the translator and shifts LBA addresses with minimal impact on performance while G-List reallocation do have some effect on performance.

Argument that a drive has 1000's of sectors to spare IMO is nonsense:

1. These 1000's of spare sectors are spread out across the drive so that if sectors are reallocated the r/w heads don't have to travel to the other end of the drive. So the purpose of there being many spare sectors is so that they can be spread so that to reallocation can be done using a relatively nearby spare and thus performance impact is as minimal as possible.
2. The thousands of sectors are BTW 2350 sectors in this case(*).
3. If you're going to wait with retiring the drive until it has reallocated 100's of sectors you run a high risk of losing data or if data is properly backed up, a high risk of the drive failing at some inconvenient moment.

It is also worth considering that these 94 sectors are sectors the drive knows about at this point in time while there may be actually be more problematic sectors.

---

(*) SMART specs Seagate: https://t1.daumcdn.net/brunch/service/user/axm/file/zRYOdwPu3OMoKYmBOby1fEEQEbU.pdf

> **3.4 Attribute ID 5: Retired Sectors Count**
>
> Normalized Retired Sectors Count = 100 - (100 * NumberOfRetiredSectors
> / (MinimumNumberOfSparesAvailable)) where
> MinimumNumberOfSparesAvailable depends on factory certification
> method, and available spare locations.

With our normalized value = 96 and reallocated RAW = 94 ..

MinimumNumberOfSparesAvailable = 100 * 94 / (100 - 96)

MinimumNumberOfSparesAvailable = 100 * 94 / 4

MinimumNumberOfSparesAvailable = 2350

Comment: The final of the story: I noticed that the disk was still on 3-years warranty and returned it to seller. The seller gave me my money back. Thanks for advice.